# Spring Async with 2 calls

Tags: java, spring

I am using the annotation @Async in my methods.For code which makes a isolated calls to the third party the behavior of Async is perfect.But in one of the case when my program runs i make two calls to the 3rd party both in async mode.The problem now is that I want the calls to async made to third party in order.Need suggestion if that is possible.I want the async to remain as is(as performance is in question making the call to be invoked in sequence)Let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Just put the 2 calls one after the other inside the same method annotated with `@Async` Spring will run the entire method asynchronously, but the two method calls will be run in programmatic order.

Comment: @JamesMassey , thanks for the suggestion.However we still wanted to have the methods in Async mode , is there any way 2 async calls made in sequence by the programs are in order mode while making call to the third party ?

Comment: No, that's the entire point of `@Async`. If your second call has to wait for the first to finish, you can't invoke each method asynchronously. You can invoke one after the other asynchronously. If the second call doesn't have to wait for the first to finish, just mark both as `@Async`

Answer (score 2):

I believe if your first method returns a Future<> you can create a new @Async method that calls the first method then waits for the Future to complete.  Then call the second method and wait or don't wait for it to complete.